# Can you change the background image each time you click the button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-image

I've checked the documentation and have successfully added an image as a background, however, I can't change it now that it's been set.

What I want to do is to change the background Image each time I click the button. Looking online I've found information on how to change the buttons background, but not the actual background.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var arrays = ["A", "b", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    var currentIndex = 0
    var image = UIImage()
    var image3 = UIImage()

    @IBOutlet weak var ChangeText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ChangeText.text = arrays[currentIndex]

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "LaunchImage")!)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image2")!)
    }

    @IBAction func Button() {
        currentIndex += 1

        if currentIndex == arrays.count {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
        ChangeText.text = arrays[currentIndex]

        if image == UIImage(named: "Image2") {
            print("Image")
        }
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image2")!)
    }
}
```

Also is it OK to force unwrap UIImage I know force unwrapping is frowned upon however I know for sure that I will have a background image.

I tried this as well but Im having the same problem it wont change the background image more than once.

```

```
    @IBAction func Button() {
        currentIndex += 1

        if currentIndex == arrays.count {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
        ChangeText.text = arrays[currentIndex]

        if image == UIImage(named: "Image2") {
            print("Image")
        }
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image2")!)

        if image3 == UIImage(named: "Image3") {
            print("Image")
        }
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image3")!)
    }
}
```

```

Comment: i am not seeing code where you are changing background image apart from viewDidLoad

Comment: In `Button()` you change the value of `ChangeText` but you don't change `self.view.backgroundColor` like you did in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Rajat sorry about that

Comment: @Alia.RK add breakpoint in your button action method and check whether button action is triggered or not

Comment: @Rajat Sorry I'm not sure what you mean I added the breakpoint and the code stopped once it got to the button method and it is properly connected i checked in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the problem is, as you haven't shown us what you have already tried.

The same code that you have used to set the background view can be used anywhere, and as often as you like

```
    if <some condition>
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "one")!)
    }
    if <another condition>
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "two")!)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Russell I've tried this but when I run it in the simulator it skips image2 and goes to image3 it only changes the background  image once when I click the button.   I've added the code to show you what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question is related to the buttons so much as general concepts, like conditions. As Russel answered, you simply need conditions. You've already demonstrated image loading is doable, so now you just need to do it "again" with a different image.

I have a few tips. First, don't name functions with nouns, say ButtonTapped or similar. Button, in swift 3, will be/is a UIButton, so it won't work as you expect anyway.

I realize you were not changing the Button's background, but I thought you were. If you were, Buttons don't behave like images and views. They have "Background for state" and "title for state". Heck, you can't even scale them using Core Animation, you have to scale their superview to see it. Although I'd hold off on Core Animation for now.

What you want to do is what Russel said, but try something simple. Like:

```
var switch:bool = true;

func buttonTapped() {
   if (switch == true) {
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "one");
   } else {
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "two");
   }
   switch = !switch;
}
```

I would first do something easy though to prove it's working
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor(); and orange/white anything.

Whether you should force unwrap things or not, gaining good naming habits, understanding structure, etc... I would recommend learning C++. A simple C++ tutorial will cover more structure and modularization than any beginner book on swift or iPhone programming. Plus, every other language is just a fraction of its features, so you'll pick everything else up super quick.

Comment: Hi @Stephen J  thanks for your help this seems to have worked however I want the background to keep on changing with each click but given its an else statement as soon as a condition is false it wont check any other condition that  might add

Comment: Right. So what you've done so far is prove that you can change the image, and that your logic is being recognized. At this point you just update it. You'll need more images, decide if you want a list to repeat or random. 
If you name your images image1, image2 then you can use a StringWithFormat:@"image%i", num and make num a static or instance variable that is incremented every time the button is pressed.
If it is random then you just do something like number = arc4random() %maxNumber; imageName = "image\(number).png"; This comment is in Obj C and Swift, btw, don't take it word for word.

Comment: this is a bit random but would you be able to provide tutoring on swift and IOS.You seem to know what your doing and in all honestly Im finding it to be a bit of a struggle learning everything by myself. I don't know any programmers and have no one to go to regarding programming. I'm willing to work at it I just think if you have a teacher to guide you slightly it makes the learning curve slightly easier. Let me know if there's any way I can contact you about this. Apologies if I've caused any inconvenience

Comment: Oddly enough I've been randomly asked to tutor everything from iOS to Java to android lately, so I'm not too surprised, heh. But I will shove that into a private message with info on where to contact.

Comment: I seem to be unable to send pm's here, the inbox must be for comments only. I'll update my profile with my wyzant when I reactivate it in a week. It'll be by Dec 4th or near then. I don't want to violate any terms by posting things in the comments with direct info, but my profile can have a few media's on it, so check back in a week-about. And remember, feel free to explore. Compilers won't punish you for doing it wrong, just change and do it again, have fun, try different things, compare. Also go to leetcode or codewars for practice

Comment: Thank you so much for responding no worries I will do, and yep until then I'll keep practising. thanks for your time :)

Comment: I've been running around a lot. My profile has my website, with a contact page. It's not a final draft by any means, and some is testing for an app for a friend (like the random religious page that doesn't belong there) but it gets you a way to email me without me sending contact info here. I'll probably delete this comment after you find the contact form. I'm on WyzAnt near the area in my profile, as a tutor, too.
See you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
           @IBAction func Button() {
            currentIndex += 1

            if currentIndex == arrays.count {
                currentIndex = 0
            }
            ChangeText.text = arrays[currentIndex]

            if image == UIImage(named: "Image2")
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image3")!)
                return;
            }
            else if image3 == UIImage(named: "Image3")
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image4")!)
                return;
            }
            else if image == UIImage(named: "Image")
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image2")!)
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image")!)
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: if image == UIImage(named: "Image\(currentIndex)")
if ( currentIndex > arrays.Count - 1 ) { currentIndex = 0; }. This pattern replaces if/switch when you can find a pattern. If the images were named randomly, then use if statements, or rename your files to match a pattern. I see you already got the > count part. I was taught that when possible, account for skipping, so I use > and not ==, Andre LaMothe taught me.